# IntentService intents are null and networkonmainthread is thrown

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am sending data from GcmIntentService that I have received from GCM servers, to an IntentService directly using intent. But my intent is null in the onHandleIntent method of the IntentService. I have OnLocationChanged method in that IntentService that takes those strings passsed to that null intent, and strangely enough they are not null.

```
@Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

                if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {//this is for the initial updates before any requests by the user
                    if ( data.containsKey("ipaid")){
                        String passenger = data.getString("ipaid");

                        Intent iniupdates = new Intent(MyGcmListenerService.this, InitialLocationUpdater.class);
                        iniupdates.putExtra(InitialLocationUpdater.PARAM_IN_P, passenger);
                        iniupdates.putExtra(InitialLocationUpdater.PARAM_IN_D, tok);
                        iniupdates.putExtra("lat", la);
                        iniupdates.putExtra("lon", lo);
                        startService(iniupdates); 
                    }
}

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && mLastLocation != null) {
            pa = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_P); <----here pa and dr are null
            dr = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_D);

            sendLocation(dr, String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()), pa); <--this throws npe b/c dr and pa
        } else{
            Log.e("ERROR", "SOME OF YOUR INTENT IS NULL");
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (location != null) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Log.i("info", "Latitude :: " + latitude);
            Log.i("info", "Longitude :: " + longitude);
            //sending location details
            Log.e("lochabged", pass);
            sendLocation(dr, String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude), pa); <--here pa and dr are not null
        }
    }
```

I am also getting W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException within the IntentService. Doesn't it run on a worker thread? This class was previously a service and I deleted it renamed it and clean my project but I am still getting the same error.

```
10-09 13:42:16.317 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-09 13:42:16.320 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
10-09 13:42:16.321 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
10-09 13:42:16.321 30850-30850/mypackage W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-09 13:42:16.322 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-09 13:42:16.322 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-09 13:42:16.322 30850-30850/mypackage W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
10-09 13:42:16.322 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
10-09 13:42:16.323 30850-30850/mypackage W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
10-09 13:42:16.323 30850-30850/mypackage W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
10-09 13:42:16.323 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
10-09 13:42:16.323 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
10-09 13:42:16.325 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
10-09 13:42:16.326 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
10-09 13:42:16.326 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
10-09 13:42:16.327 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at mypackage .InitialLocationUpdater.sendLocation(InitialLocationUpdater.java:136)
10-09 13:42:16.327 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at mypackage .InitialLocationUpdater.onLocationChanged(InitialLocationUpdater.java:118)
10-09 13:42:16.328 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzk$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
10-09 13:42:16.329 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-09 13:42:16.329 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-09 13:42:16.329 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-09 13:42:16.329 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 13:42:16.330 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 13:42:16.330 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-09 13:42:16.331 30850-30850/mypackage W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-09 13:42:16.331 30850-30850/mypackage  W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Look at your stack trace.  `onHandleIntent(...)` is called in a worker thread, but `onLocationChanged(...)` isn't.

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede, how do I change that behavior?  Why did that happen at the first place?

Comment: `onLocationChanged()` is called for elsewhere by the system. It's up to the caller which thread to call it on, and it seems the system calls it on the main thread. I doubt you can change that behavior, but you can at least check which thread you're on inside of `onLocationChanged()` and schedule your work on another thread instead.

Comment: What @Karakuri said. Android has a very strong convention of callbacks occurring in the main thread.  This usually makes everything easier.  But if the listener needs to use the network, you need to make it asynchronous yourself, either with an `AsyncTask` or by using a network library that does things in the background for you.